# JS doesn't change the value of input

Tags: javascript, input, cart, shopping-cart

I'm writing cart-box that will change the quantity of products in cart. It works only if I have one box (one product) in cart, but when I have more products in cart it changes the value of the first input only.

This is my html code (earlier in the code I've got loop for my products):

```
<div class="amount">
    <a>
       <button type="button" class="minus">-</button>
    </a>
       <input class="amount-input" th:type="text" th:value="1" th:min="1"/>
    <a> 
       <button type="button" class="plus">+</button>
    </a>
</div>
```

And this is JS code:

```
$('.minus').click(function () {
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    var input = parseInt(parent.find(".amount-input").val());
    var count = input - 1;

    //input['value'] = count;
    //parent.closest("input").value = count;
    document.querySelector("input").value = count;
});

$('.plus').click(function () {
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    var input = parseInt(parent.find(".amount-input").val());
    var count = input + 1;

    //input['value'] = count;
    //parent.closest("input").value = count;
    document.querySelector("input").value = count;
});
```

I know that `document.querySelector("input").value = count` changes the first input only, because it's first on the list, but `input['value'] = count` doesn't change anything, `parent.closest("input").value = count` either.

Comment: looks like input is a number, what are you expecting input['value'] = count to do?

Comment: change the value of input -1 or +1

Comment: This probably won't fix your problem, but the best way to get the parent element in jQuery is to use `this.parent()`

Comment: try parent.querySelector instead of document.querySelector

Comment: it returns error 
Uncaught TypeError: parent.querySelector is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>

Comment: Step 1. Use valid HTML , as a rule, you can't nest interactive content. E.g. a `button` in an `a` tag. Further more this appears to be using the jQuery library, and is not plain javascript

Comment: And yet more... `th:type="text" th:value="1" th:min="1"` is not standard HTML. What is it? What precisely do you want to update, all `input` fields or just the one in the same parent?

Comment: I want to updated one field, and it's thymeleaf for spring boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use valid HTML, otherwise results are not guaranteed.

Next let's remove duplication and just use the one event listener for both buttons, changing the value added based on the presence of the `plus` class.

Finally, if you're using jQuery, stick to using jQuery methodology. Also, you are doing nothing here with jQuery that couldn't be done with simple, native, javascript.

```js
//Use one event listener for both
$('.amount button').click(function () {
    //Find the nearest ancestor with class amoun
    var parent = $(this).closest(".amount");
    //Note you need to still use $ with jQuery Objecyd
    var input = $(parent).find(".amount-input");
    //Set the count based on the class of the button click
    var count = parseInt($(input).val()) + ($(this).hasClass("plus") ? 1 : -1 );
    //Set the value
    $(input).val(count);   
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="amount">
       <button type="button" class="minus">-</button>
       <input class="amount-input" type="text" value="1" min="1"/>
       <button type="button" class="plus">+</button>
</div>

<div class="amount">
       <button type="button" class="minus">-</button>
       <input class="amount-input" type="text" value="1" min="1"/>
       <button type="button" class="plus">+</button>
</div>
```